# Not able to replace text in all pages of a multi page PDF file using iText7 PDFCleanup java Library

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I have PDFs with **large number of pages** containing PII data like SSN. I need to replace the SSN with some dummy value before sharing the PDF. I am exploring the usage of iText and it's PDFCleanup plugin. Overall, the library looks promising in replacing the text. However, I have landed into a problem:

I am able to redact i.e. cleanup the text from any page of the PDF. However, I am only able to replace the text on the first page. Text from any subsequent page doesn't gets replaced.

My sample code is:

```
private void replaceTextInDocument(PdfDocument pdfDocument, String textToReplace, String replacementText) throws IOException {
    CompositeCleanupStrategy strategy = new CompositeCleanupStrategy();
    strategy.add(new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(textToReplace).setRedactionColor(ColorConstants.WHITE));
    PdfCleaner.autoSweepCleanUp(pdfDocument, strategy);
    System.out.println("----STRATEGY SIZE:  " + strategy.getResultantLocations().size());

    for (IPdfTextLocation location : strategy.getResultantLocations()) {
        System.out.println("----PAGE #: " + location.getPageNumber() + " TEXT: " + location.getText());
        PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(location.getPageNumber() + 1);
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(), page.getResources(), page.getDocument());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, location.getRectangle());
        canvas.add(new Paragraph(replacementText).setFontSize(8).setMarginTop(0f)
              .setRotationAngle(Math.toRadians(90))
        );
    }
}
```

Bit of debugging has unraveled that if the *textToReplace* exists on a page other than the first, the *strategy.getResultantLocations()* has a size of 0. So, the code doesn't enters the for loop to replace the text.

Probably the confusing part is that PDFCleaner is able to clean/redact the text on any page.

I am not sure if I am missing anything here or it's the limitation of the library. The code samples that I have seen online use only one pager PDFs.

Thanks and Regards

***EDITING** my question to add more info as per comment by @mkl. Adding info here would improve readability as compared to adding plain text comment. Also, this would result in continuity of the steps followed and resolution.*

I am in PoC Stage and running a standalone java program.

I explored the option of creating a custom strategy based on *RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy*. To understand the same, I debugged this class. Please refer to the code in the RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy.getResultantLocations() method

```
 public Collection<IPdfTextLocation> getResultantLocations() {
        // align characters in "logical" order
        Collections.sort(parseResult, new TextChunkLocationBasedComparator(new DefaultTextChunkLocationComparator()));

        // process parse results
        List<IPdfTextLocation> retval = new ArrayList<>();

        CharacterRenderInfo.StringConversionInfo txt = CharacterRenderInfo.mapString(parseResult);

        Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(txt.text);
        while (mat.find()) {
            Integer startIndex = getStartIndex(txt.indexMap, mat.start(), txt.text);
            Integer endIndex = getEndIndex(txt.indexMap, mat.end() - 1);
            if (startIndex != null && endIndex != null && startIndex <= endIndex) {
                for (Rectangle r : toRectangles(parseResult.subList(startIndex.intValue(), endIndex.intValue() + 1))) {
                    retval.add(new DefaultPdfTextLocation(0, r, mat.group(0)));
                }
            }
        }

        /* sort
         * even though the return type is Collection<Rectangle>, we apply a sorting algorithm here
         * This is to ensure that tests that use this functionality (for instance to generate pdf with
         * areas of interest highlighted) will not break when compared.
         */
        Collections.sort(retval, new PdfTextLocationComparator());

        // ligatures can produces same rectangle
        removeDuplicates(retval);

        return retval;
    }
```

The *parseResults* and subsequent *txt.text* always contain the content from the Page 1 of the PDF irrespective of the fact which page of PDF contains the *pattern*. So, the *mat.find()* evaluates to false and hence the *while()* loop is not executed. So, nothing gets added to the *retVal* and as a result *strategy.getResultantLocations()* returns 0.

At this stage, I cannot say that hard coded 0 for *DefaultPdfTextLocation* is an issue or not.

Any idea why the following is happening or pointers for further debugging  would be helpful:

- Why the *RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy* is not able to read or
  add content for pages other than Page 1.

Answer (score 0):

> Bit of debugging has unraveled that if the textToReplace exists on a page other than the first, the strategy.getResultantLocations() has a size of 0. So, the code doesn't enters the for loop to replace the text.

This observation is pointing to the cause of the issue: During redaction a fresh cleanup strategy is required for each page. Thus, the `reset` method of the used cleanup strategy is called. Both the strategy classes you use - `CompositeCleanupStrategy` and `RegexBasedCleanupStrategy` - implement that method by actually generating a *new* instance and initializing it like the original was initialized. Thus, the strategy objects you have a hold on in your code were only used on the first page and, consequentially, only contain the resultant locations on that first page.

Another issue is that `RegexBasedCleanupStrategy` in its `getResultantLocations` uses a constant page number '0' in all the `DefaultPdfTextLocation` it generates and returns.

One way to fix this, therefore, is to derive your own strategy from `RegexBasedCleanupStrategy` with an extra method for retrieving *all* text location objects and a collection of all reset-ed instances. In that method all the instances would be visited, their locations retrieved having their respective page numbers corrected, and returned in a new collection. `reset` would be adapted to generate instances of your strategy class and would manage sharing the list of all instances.

Comment: Thanks @mkl for quick response. I explored the option of creating a custom strategy and have shared my findings by adding more info to the question for readability. Please share your thoughts on the same.

Comment: I'll look into that next week.

Comment: Hi @mkl, did you get a chance to look into this.

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately...